# Streaming a PHP Barcode to and IMG tag

Tags: php, email, shopify, barcode

I have a unique problem where I have to use only HTML because of platform constraints to send out receipt emails.

The receipts need to have a CODE128 Barcode generated on them. Unfortunately because I can only use HTML in the email template I am looking to figure out how to create these barcodes and link them with an IMG tag.

So my current idea is to use the PDFCrowd php library on a different server and then create an IMG tag in the email template with the SRC being a GET Request URL to the other server with the php library on it.

Then I would generate html with inline css and convert that to an image and stream it back out.

***Would the HTML Email Template IMG tag work with that type of URL Setup!?***

...This is for a quick and dirty shopify solution.

```
<?php
require 'pdfcrowd.php';

try
{
    // create the API client instance
    $client = new \Pdfcrowd\HtmlToImageClient("username", "apikey");

    // configure the conversion
    $client->setOutputFormat("png");

    // create output file for conversion result
    $output_file = fopen("HelloWorld.png", "wb");

    // run the conversion and store the result into an image variable
    $image = $client->convertString("<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>");

    // write the image the into the output file
    fwrite($output_file, $image);

    // close the output file
    fclose($output_file);
}
catch(\Pdfcrowd\Error $why)
{
    // report the error to the standard error stream
    fwrite(STDERR, "Pdfcrowd Error: {$why}\n");
}

?>
```

Comment: Why not just use a base64 encoded image in your HTML?

Comment: Interesting I was unaware of base64 encoding. What I've been tasked with is essentially creating custom barcodes on every different order. The shopify email template only allows HTML and order information variables. No other code. So I don't know how I could encode that information under the current platform constraints.

Comment: This codepen creates the HTML necessary, but I've had trouble sending the barcodes through e-mail in the past. E-mail clients have styles they like to apply to the img tags that render the barcodes unreadable. https://codepen.io/notionovus/pen/GMwZBx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a barcode generator that can be found on [github here](https://github.com/davidscotttufts/php-barcode/). I remember being in a similar need sometime back, downloaded the barcode generator and it got the job done.

**Example 1:**

Parameters:

- Text: “0” (Default)
- Size: “20” (Default)
- Code Type: “Code128” (Default)
- Orientation: “Horizontal” (Default)

HTML Source Code:

```
<img alt="testing" src="/code/barcode.php" />
```

Result:

[image]

**Example 2:**

Parameters:

- Text: “testing”
- Size: “20” (Default)
- Code Type: “Code128” (Default)
- Orientation: “Horizontal” (Default)
- Print: “true”

HTML Source Code:

```
<img alt="testing" src="/code/barcode.php?text=testing&print=true" />
```

Result:

[image]

**Example 3:**

Parameters:

- Text: “TESTING”
- Size: “40”
- Code Type: “Code39”
- Orientation: “Horizontal” (Default)
- Print: “true”

HTML Source Code:

```
<img alt="TESTING" src="/code/barcode.php?codetype=Code39&size=40&text=TESTING&print=true" />
```

Result:

[image]

More examples in the source link.

[Source: David Scott Tufts](http://davidscotttufts.com/2009/03/31/how-to-create-barcodes-in-php/)

Comment: Thank you this is an approach I was looking to implement but was unsure if a .php extension for the image src would render correctly. It seems it does according to your experience so I can now move ahead and be confident I can implement for the client.