# Insert single time coupon codes as bar codes in Netsuite HTML email template

Tags: html, netsuite, email-templates

I'm trying to create an HTML email template that displays a bar code of a single-use coupon code dynamically in Netsuite through marketing campaign using this

```
<barcode codetype="code128" showtext="true" value="${campaignEvent.couponCode}"/>
```

and nothing is showing up, but when I try to print out the coupon code using `${campaignEvent.couponCode}` it is getting printed correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Streaming a PHP Barcode to and IMG tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642144/streaming-a-php-barcode-to-and-img-tag)

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, BFO is only used for PDF generation and not email templates.

You can use an online barcode API such as [Barcodes4.me](http://www.barcodes4.me/apidocumentation) and embed the result in an image:

```
<img src="http://www.barcodes4.me/barcode/c128a/${campaignEvent.couponCode}.png?IsTextDrawn=1" />
```

Another similar service is [bwip-js-api](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js/wiki/Online-Barcode-API)

Comment: Got it ... Thanks! That's exactly what I want.

Comment: It seems like barcodes4 api is not for generating codes that are bigger than 7 characters and however the bwip-js-api is working for any length but it isn't accepting the variable, instead it is just treating it as a string and generating the barcode for special characters too. Is there a way I can pass the variable to the parameter that's already there on the url?

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct syntax for creating a barcode on a PDF and I've used it quite a bit.

However you write you are creating an html email and I doubt the barcode tag will generate anything in html. Can you share the source of the created email around where you expect the barcode to be? You could generate a pdf with the barcode and attach it to the email.

Or you could generate the barcodes as svg values in a batch and update a custom field on the customer and then include the field contents your html that way.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsbarcode is a bar code generator that works in multiple environments so it's possible it could be made to work in a mass update script.

Comment: I've also tried storing the field value in to a variable using #assign and then using it in the value field of the barcode tag but still no luck

<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="width: 600px; height: auto;" class="responsive-table">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">
<center><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="true" value="${campaignEvent.couponCode}"/></center>
<center>${campaignEvent.couponCode} </center>
</tr>
</td> 
</table>

Comment: To clarify `<barcode… />` is a BFO extension for making PDFs. It won’t generate any output for HTML.

Comment: yeah! I just see that and is there a way to do that in HTML? preferably I want the customer to find their coupon code directly on their email

Comment: Yes. generate it into a custom rich text field as a .svg using the library linked in my answer